# How to connect AWS EKS's pod to external databases such as MongoDB in an EC2?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc, amazon-eks

I want to deploy my full stack application using `AWS EKS`, with the backend pod connected to the databases(`MongoDB` hosted in an `EC2` instance and a `RDS Postgres`) outside of the cluster. If the `EK`S cluster and the databases are in different `VPC`, how should I configure the pod to connect to the databases after the `VPC` peer connection, do I just have to specify the external DNS name of the databases in the pod's deployment yaml?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a kubernetes Service named for example  rds-postgres-service of type ExternalName aliasing the RDS endpoint your_RDS_endpoint_URL.

Run `kubectl apply -f rds_postgres_service.yam`l to create the service. in your rds_postgres_service.yaml your code should be like this example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: rds-postgres-service
  name: rds-postgres-service
spec:
  externalName: your_RDS_endpoint_URL
  selector:
    app: rds-postgres-service
  type: ExternalName
status:
  loadBalancer: {}

# Replace your_RDS_endpoint_URL with your RDS endpoint
```

Now, clients running inside the pods within the cluster can connect to the RDS instance using: rds-postgres-service

Comment: Hey Asri thanks for the solution! In the pod's deployment yaml, do I just specify the external DNS name of the databases as http://rds-postgres-service.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local? Or should I use the RDS_endpoint_URL? Also, how should I include the secret(credentials to the RDS instance)to the rds_postgres_service.yaml?

Comment: Enable "dns propagation" in the peering connection, and use the rds enpoint url.
 For PostgreSQL credentials you can use config maps for storing PostgreSQL related Configureation.

Comment: Do I follow the same process to connect to MongoDB hosted in an EC2 instance?

Comment: Yes, create external service in your cluster to point MongoDB, after you confirming the DNS resolution between the two VPCs